# Margin: auto Not Working Properly

Tags: html, css, margin

This is my HTML.  I am trying to have three floating divs with centered images and descriptions

```
<div class=icons>
                    <div class=iconslist><img class=iconimages src="gas.png"><div class=iconlabels>The EPA Estimates <b>10%</b> of air pollution comes from lawn care</div></div>
                    <div class=iconslist><img class=iconimages src="stack.png"><div class=iconlabels>Over <b>800,000,000 gallons</b> of gasoline are used per year on lawn care</div></div>
                    <div class=iconslist><img class=iconimages src="noise.png"><div class=iconlabels>Gasoline mowers are <b>400%</b> louder than electric mowers</div></div>
            </div>
```

This is my CSS

```
.icons {
width: 606px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.iconslist {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: white;
}
.iconimages {
height: 70px;
width: 70px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
.iconlabels {
width: 180px; 
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
```

For some reason I can't get the images to center.  The text centers with the exact same code, so I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `text-align:center;` to your `.iconslist` CSS.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Any idea why `align-content: center` doesn't work?  I figured centering an image was "content" not "text"

Comment: @Teldridge11 hey have a look at my answer. It gives you explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `text-align` in W3C:
*The text-align property specifies the horizontal alignment of **text** in an element.*

So you should put `text-align` in the parent css , `.iconslist`in this situation may work.

**Solution:** you better add this in `.iconimages`

```
display: block;
```

**Explanation:** You've already known that setting a content horizontal center is using `margin: 0 auto;`, it's now working because img is an inline element.  inline content is displayed with no line breaks before or afterwards.